# delegate for object passes itself to delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a subclass of UIImageView and would like to pass self as a parameter to the delegate.  I get a error "Expected ')' before MyImageView".  I need to pass the object to the delegate so the delegate can read certain properties from the object.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol MyImageViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) buttonPressedForView:(MyImageView *) imageView;  //line with ERROR...
@end

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {
    id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
    BOOL _imageMode;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) BOOL imageMode;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need a forward declaration of MyImageView before your protocol declaration.

```
@class MyImageView;

@protocol MyImageViewDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void) buttonPressedForView:(MyImageView *) imageView;
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define the protocol after defining the MyImageView interface?? it seems that the method its not recognizing MyImageView class type, or just define the protocol in a new .h and import your current .h.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MyImageView; <<ADD THIS LINE
@protocol MyImageViewDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) buttonPressedForView:(MyImageView *) imageView;  //line with ERROR...
@end

@interface MyImageView : UIImageView {
    id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
    BOOL _imageMode;
}

@property (nonatomic,assign) id <MyImageViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic,readonly) BOOL imageMode;
```